# Can too low brightness damage my screen?

Tags: laptop, screen, brightness, backlight

I can modify `/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness` to set brightness of the screen.

Previously I had Windows installed, and the lowest brightness went down to some certain point, however, on Linux, and by modifying that manually or by using `xfce4`, I can get the screen brightness too low, way way lower than the lowest on Windows.

So I am asking, do I use this as a feature? or could it possibly damage the hardware?

What I mean by very low is like, barely backlit, the point it becomes really hard to read something on a typically lighted room.

Like I can get the `brightness` down to `1` on Linux, while the equivalent of Windows' lowest brightness is like `100`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lowering brightness cannot damage screen in any way. However it can damage your eyes to look on too dark screen. That's why Windows doesn't offer lower values.

LED monitor does not require Light to work. There are many leds which form the picture, but they are not the source of light. The source of light which you can control (brigthness) is behind those leds. There is no way leds are destroyed by not being properly iluminited.

You can see nice picture in source im adding.

You can lower your brightness at your will.

Hope I helped.

Sources:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid-crystal_display

https://www.quora.com/Vision-eyesight-What-is-the-ideal-computer-screen-brightness-level-for-eye-health

Comment: Any source for your information?

Comment: Edited. You can see sources as well as some more information about why I am convinced.